# number of consecutive seats intuition

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, intuition

So I am trying to solve some problems with combinatorics, probability...
One problem asks for the probability that k people will seat one next to the other in n seats (n>k).This is an easy problem, but it’s not very intuitive why all the possible adjacent seats are n-k+1, I could solve it just by making a sketch, but I can’t really see why.Hope some of you can give me this intuition.;)

Comment: intuition comes often, if you start with small numbers, so take n=5 and k=2 and next 3, maybe try also n=7 and k =3

Comment: What is the answer to this “easy” problem? I worked out a very incorrect solution when I tried it myself

Comment: well that’s what I did to find all the possible ways in which you can arrange all consecutive seats, but cannot understand intuitively why the general formula holds

Comment: @IdioticShrike basically you find the total ways in which you can arrange consecutive k seats and divide by the total ways in which k people can seat in n seats.

Comment: Count avoiding the fencepost error https://betterexplained.com/articles/learning-how-to-count-avoiding-the-fencepost-problem/